# error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0

Tags: swift, version

I am trying to make an Xcode (version 10.2) project. I have only used Swift 5.0 in my life and but I get an error:

> "error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are:
>   4.0, 4.2, 5.0.(in Target Quizzler)"

I have tried a lot of ways on Stack Overflow that have been recommended but none of them seem to work.
Is there a way to solve this?

Making all the swift versions in swift build settings 5.0, making `SWIFT_SWIFT3_OBJC_INFERENCE` yes instead of no.

No code.

It is supposed to be a quiz but it gives me an error:

> SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2,
>   5.0.(in Target Quizzler) error.

Comment: You try to open existing project in Xcode 10.2 or it is new project?

Comment: It is an existing project. I worked on it for an hour before encountering error.